# Troubleshooting Program using sensors and actuators

Tags: programming

I am doing a project on waste management. I have to separate waste majorly as metal, plastic and other materials. For that using Arduino Mega 2560. I have connected Inductive proximity sensor @ A0 (Anolog pin 1 of Arduino) & Capacitive proximity Sensor @ A1(analog pin 2 of Arduino). The two 5V DC motor which are to be used as actuators when the sensors sense the object. 
I have given 12 V to the 2 sensors and I have directly connected the sensor's output pin with arduino.

If the Inductive sensor senses any metal object in the conveyor, the dc motor which is a actuator here has to rotate forward, wait sometime and to rotate reverse and stay until the next sense started.
The same for capacitive sensor.

But the problem was there is even though the sensor is not sensing the motor is running. The motor keeps on running forward, delayed and reverse. Please help me out for this, I don't know where I have done the mistake.

The program I have tried is here:

```
#define motorpin1 4 \\dc motor's pin 1
#define motorpin2 5 \\dc motor's pin 2
#define motorpin3 6 \\dc motor's pin 3
#define motorpin4 7 \\dc motor's pin 4


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(A0,INPUT); 
  pinMode(A1,INPUT);
  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT); 


}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
if((analogRead(A0)<400) && (analogRead(A0)>100)
{
  digitalWrite(motorpin1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorpin2,LOW);
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(motorpin1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorpin2,HIGH);
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(motorpin1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorpin1,LOW);

}
if((analogRead(A1)<400) && (analogRead(A1)>100)
{
  digitalWrite(motorpin3,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorpin4,LOW);
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(motorpin3,LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorpin4,HIGH);
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(motorpin3,LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorpin4,LOW);

}
```

Comment: That sketch does not compile. We like to see the sketch that causes the problem that you describe. Can you tell more about the sensors? Can you tell us the brand, type, and a link to them please. What is connected to pin 8 and 9?

Comment: And what is the circuit like? I mean, how are the sensors and actuators connected?
Maybe you have an "open collector" sensor, and consequently need a pull-up/pull-down, maybe your sensor sends you a "reverse" voltage value.
For sure your code can be improved by removing all those delays and properly designing the phases, otherwise the board will become "blind" to the other sensor when moving one actuator

Comment: what are the outputs of the two sensors like? ..... forget about the motors for now ..... write a sketch that prints out the output values of the sensors and add the findings to your question